# Bean property 'sessionFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have 1 error:

`Invalid property 'sessionFactory' of bean class [com.aptech.mavenspringmvc.dao.StudentDAOImpl]: Bean property 'sessionFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?`

[image]

[image]

File DAO implement

```
@Repository
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO{
    @Autowired
public SessionFactory session;
```

File DAO

```
@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService{

//@Autowired
public StudentDAO studao;

public void setStudao(StudentDAO studao) {
    this.studao = studao;
}

public StudentDAO getStudao() {
    return studao;
}
```

File controller

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {
// @Autowired
private StudentService stuSer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Repository
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO{

 @Autowired
 public SessionFactory sessionFactory;
 ....

 public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
     this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but still not working with this error

Answer (score 0):

In the XML configuration, you are setting **sessionFactory** property of **studDao** bean.

But the property is named as **session** in the code that you posted.

Comment: Do you have a setter method for the "session" property in DaoImpl?